# Не запускается сервер через команду node index.js

Tags: node.js

Сервер не запускается через команду `node index.js`, хотя через команду `npm start` запускается, стоит `babel7` и `nodemon`. Выдает ошибку:

```
import http from 'http'
       ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
```

Код `index.js`:

```
'use strict';

// 1: NPM dependencies.
import http from 'http'
import express from 'express'
import logger from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import passport from 'passport';

// 2: App related modules.
// ... Nothing here, yet!

// 3: Initializations.
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const apiRoutes = require('./src/routes/routes').default;

// 4: Parse as urlencoded and json.
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

// 5: Hook up the HTTP logger.
app.use(logger('dev'));

// 6: Hook up Passport.
app.use(passport.initialize());

// 7: Set the static files location.

// 8: Home route.
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome',
}));

// Bundle API routes.
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

// 9: Start the server.
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Мой `package.json`:

```
  ...
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
     "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.398.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cron": "^1.6.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "generate-password": "^1.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.8.0"
  },
  ...
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Ваша Нода импорты не поддерживает, я так думаю

Comment: А какая поддерживает?

Comment: `"start": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js"` эта строка ведь не просто так? Она запускает node с параметрами, где вы используете `babel`. А запуск `node index.js` модуль `babel` волшебным образом не подтянет. А без `babel` node не понимает инструкции import

Comment: То есть надо изменить скрипт на `"start": "nodemon --exec babel-node node 
 index.js" `. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Megaroks нет. Команда `node index.js` запускает выполнение файла, а `npm start` запускает в соответствии с конфигурацией `package.json`

Comment: Тогда как мне запустить командой `node index.js` мой сервер, не переделывая `import` на `require`?

Comment: @MegaRoks, согласно оф. документации `node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs`, я такой вариант не пробовал. Посмотрите свою версию node, скорее всего стоит обновиться до последней стабильной(разработчики движка стараются внедрять новые функции ES6 и выше). НО `npm start` в вашей ситуации, то что вам нужно.